# Extraction Flash Calculation - 4 Component and 2 Phase System

Tags: chemical-engineering, matlab

I am performing extraction flash calculations for 4 component and 2 phase system in Matlab. For anyone somewhat shaky with what extraction flash calculation is; extraction is performed, feed composition is known and we are calculating compositions of both phases at equilibrium, mole fraction of every component in both phases as well as mole fraction of both phases.

This calculation is done numerically, until convergence criterion is satisfied. I know it is possible to take calculated mole fraction difference in two consecutive iterations as a convergence criterion, but I am not sure how many criteria I should apply in case of 4 component and 2 phase system?

I am thinking I need to apply 3 such criteria for 3 components in the system for one of the phases because mole fraction of 4th component is satisfied automatically by mass balance for the phase and mole fractions of components in other phase is satisfied automatically by phase equilibrium condition or mass balance for every component.

I am not sure if this is correct?

Comment: The Chemistry Stack maybe?

Comment: Are you doing equilibrium calculations just on the output streams or are you applying Rachford-Rice over the entire system? @SolarMike ... I might hope that chemical engineers could post here too.

Comment: @SolarMike Nah, this calculation is more common in ChemE than chemistry. Chemists don't usually deal with this stuff.

Comment: @JeffreyJWeimer so if you are a chemical engineer interested in helping with chemical engineering questions, which stack would you most likely go to? Or, to put it another way, where would you most likely find the highest number of people doing chemistry?

Comment: @SolarMike Well, you seem to be saying that chemistry and ChemE are the same branch of science which they aren't. One is a branch of natural sciences and other is a branch of engineering. You think chemists refine oil, natural gas, create all kinds plastics, drugs, detergents, soaps, mineral fertilizers... in industrial machinery and bring tons of these products every day to the market?

Comment: @JeffreyJWeimer I do equilibrium calculations for the entire system. As I said, feed composition is known (we know composition of a system as whole) and than I calculate compositions of both phases and mole fraction of each phase at equilibrium. It is like laboratory extraction where you mix components in a flask and than wait for phases to separate. If you know initial composition, extraction flash algorithm calculates compositions of both phases in equilibrium and mole fraction of each phase.

Comment: CROSS POSTED here: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/163757

Comment: Yeah, that is my post. You can add chemical engineering tag there. I've forgotten that cross posting isn't allowed on stack exchange, so I've deleted the other post.

Comment: @SolarMike Unfortunately, chemists almost uniformly do not know how to tackle hard-core chemical engineering problems such as this one. Unfortunately also, the Engineering stack seems to be dominated by a mechanical engineering mindset. Well-framed questions about a challenging problem in chemical engineering can off-handedly tend to be pushed aside (because unfortunately, mechanical engineers do not seem to pay attention to what chemical engineers really do). Your opening suggestion is an example.

Comment: @JeffreyJWeimer so as you seem to be "the chemical engineer" then is the OP correct? Perhaps a better use of your effort than targeting me for suggesting the chemistry Stack may have been appropriate.

Comment: OK. You are using a Rachford-Rice approach (are you familiar with this approach?). This helps clarify how to set up an analysis for the degrees of freedom. Thanks.

Comment: @SolarMike You asked for my sentiments. Now that I understand the OP's question, it is about doing a degrees of freedom analysis. This is certainly an engineering question, albeit on a chemical engineering process not a mechanical engineering process. This is certainly not a chemistry question.

Comment: @JeffreyJWeimer Yes, there aren't many chemical engineers here. Mechanical engineers don't need to know what chemical engineers do, it is not their field of expertise. When I posted this question I didn't expect mechanical engineer to answer this, but chemical engineer. It is also true that many people (and unfortunately other fellow engineers) are ignorant about ChemE because of which comments such as one above is quite common among people.

Comment: @JeffreyJWeimer Analysis for degrees of freedom? Are you referring to the Gibbs phase rule? According to Gibbs, we have 4 degrees of freedom in this system (4 - 2 +2 = 4). I do know Rachford - Rice equation which combines mole balances for both phases in one equation. However, I didn't use that equation in my calculations because mole balance for either of the phases is enough to give all equations needed to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For reference, I am drawing from the chapter on isothermal VLE separations in Separation Process Principles by Seader, Henley, and Roper.

Consider only the final state. The two starting statements in degrees of freedom with $C'$ independent chemical components and $\Pi_{act}$ phases give the number of intensive parameters and independent intensive equations.

$$\nu = C'\Pi_{act} + 2$$

$$\epsilon = \Pi_{act} + C'(\Pi_{act} - 1)$$

For your system with $C' = 4$ and $\Pi_{act} = 2$, we find $\nu = 10$ and $\epsilon = 6$. The parameters are

$$T, p, x_j(4), y_j(4)$$

The equations are

$$\sum x_j = 1, \sum y_j = 1, K_j(T, p)(4)$$

Assuming that you have theoretical equations for partition functions $K_j(T, p) = y_j/x_i$, you will only have to specify four parameters at the end state. These generally are taken as $T, p$ (allowing you to obtain $K_j$) and two composition variables. When you do not have pre-defined theoretical equations for the partition coefficients $K_j(T,p)$, you drop three independent equations (because all four $K_j$ are not independent). You will have to measure three additional compositions to allow you to construct the $K_j$ values empirically.

When we do an isothermal flash from $N_F$ feed streams, we have these additions to the number of parameters and equations

$$\Delta \nu = N_F(C' + 1) + \Pi_act$$
$$\Delta \epsilon = N_F + C' + 1 $$

In your case, the flash adds initial compositions $z_j(4)$, initial phase amount $f_{z}$, and ending phase fractions $f_L, f_V$ as intensive parameters. You add these six independent equations

$$\sum z_j = 1, f_z = 1, f_L + f_V = 1, z_j f_z = x_j f_L + y_j f_V$$

The end result is that you must measure one further intensive parameter from the flash, typically the vapor fraction $f_V$.

Finally, a two phase flash is directly amenable to being set up for an analytical solution using a Rachford-Rice expression.

$$\sum \frac{z_j\left(1 - K_j\right)}{1 - f_V\left(1 - K_j\right)} = 0$$

Graphical analysis is easier than an iterative analysis.

The four problems that tend to crash out when doing (isothermal) flash calculations are as follows:

- Under specifying measured parameters -- measuring too few parameters to comply with the requirement from the difference between known independent equations and known intensive parameters $(\epsilon + \Delta \epsilon) - (\nu + \Delta \nu)$.
- Incorrectly specifying independent equations -- not using the correct equations or adding additional parameters in the equations. Specific examples that generally fail here involve incorrect or additional complex equations for partition functions.
- Improperly specifying parameters -- counting measured parameters that are not truly independent as part of the "independent" set. Specific examples that fail here involve measuring mole fractions for all components in one stream but ignoring any measurements in another stream.
- Over specifying parameters -- trying to analyze the system after pre-specifying more parameters than permitted by the degrees of freedom.

You might be able to judge from this which failure you happen to be approaching in your analysis.

Comment: Thank you, for the detailed answer. I am familiar with the last equation you've written (I can see it in my textbook). It's a combined equation -  combined mole balance for both phases of the system. It is derived from more basic equations such as general mole balance for components, phases and definition of partition coefficient (don't like to use term partition function because of it's meaning in statistical mechanics and thermo).

Comment: Chemical engineers don't talk to statistical mechanics folks or physicists about VLE flash. So we are comfortable using partition coefficient in this context. I suggest again that graphical analysis with the Rachford-Rice is absolutely easier than iterative analysis with anything. With care, anyone could likely solve a multi-component, two phase, isothermal VLE flash with GeoGebra, no need for MatLab. You need only to assure that you are graphing one equation with one unknown to find a zero crossing.

Comment: I solved it! I used Rachford - Rice equation as a convergence criterion in while loop and results are good. Previously I used criteria like mole fraction deviation in two iterations for every component in one phase, but in that case my calculations actually diverged from solution even though these criteria aren't wrong, but aren't based on some fundamental equation like mole balance and that isn't enough for calculation to give good results. I learned something from this.

Comment: Good to hear. From an academic standpoint (I teach a course on this), I'd be curious to see the system in detail.

Comment: We can talk about it in more detail. How do you want to get in touch since here isn't the best place to talk?